# Clarification for self.forward function in Python

Tags: python, function, class, neural-network, forward

I am not able to understand this `sample_losses = self.forward(output, y)` defined under the class `Loss`.

From which "forward function" it is taking input as forward function is previously defined for all three classes i.e. `Dense_layer`, `Activation_ReLU` and `Activation_Softmax`?

```
class Layer_Dense:
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_neurons):
        self.weights = 0.01 * np.random.randn(n_inputs, n_neurons)
        self.biases = np.zeros((1, n_neurons))
        print(self.weights)
    def forward(self, inputs):
        self.output = np.dot(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases
class Activation_ReLU:
    def forward(self, inputs):
        self.output= np.maximum(0, inputs)
class Activation_Softmax:
    def forward (self, inputs):
        exp_values = np.exp(inputs - np.max(inputs, axis = 1, keepdims= True ))
        probabilities= exp_values/np.sum(exp_values, axis = 1, keepdims= True )
        self.output = probabilities
class Loss:
    def calculate(self, output, y):
        sample_losses = self.forward(output, y)
        data_loss = np.mean(sample_losses)
        return data_loss
```

Comment: It doesnt look like it should be there like that. Most likely, thats a totally different function and someone mistook the name. Even if it would have been the function defined in the other classes before it, the function still gets one input (additionally to 'self')

Comment: Please show a [mre] of how this code is used. Currently this would probably raise an exception saying that the "forward" attribute doesn't exist (which is why you are wondering).

Comment: This website is helping me a lot. I was keep on wondering a lot!! I got the idea now. Thank you very much for the support

Answer (score 3):

self.forward() is similar to **call** method but with registered hooks. This is used to directly call a method in the class when an instance name is called. These methods are inherited from nn.Module.

https://gist.github.com/nathanhubens/5a9fc090dcfbf03759068ae0fc3df1c9

Or refer to the source code:

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L485